# How to set and change default(root) router with vue-router(Vue 3 Composition API)

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

I asked this at two other places but couldn't get a good answer. I would be grateful if anyone here could help me with this. I also think this may help other in the future.

My problem is a bit specific.
I am trying to set the "/" router to for example "/team-12" .
"team-12" is selected by user and stored in localStorage or store(Pinia).

So for example if the user selected a team, the default router will be /team-12/ (".com/team-12/settings" etc.). All the website routing will be added after "team-12/" If not selected it will be team-1 or something like that. And the user can change the team, thus the default route will change and page will refresh.

I managed to set the route to localStorage value but I get an error:

[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/team-12"

Also I can't add other routes to "/team-12". How can I achieve this? If there is a better aproach, ignore the code.

I tried this: router.ts

```
 router.ts:
    const contractId = localStorage.getItem("contractId");

  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    redirect: `/${contractId}`,
    component: Home,
  },
    
Component:
    const selectTeamId = (teamId: string) => {
      localStorage.setItem("teamId", organization);
      console.log(localStorage.getItem("teamId"));
    
      router.push({ name: "home" });
    };
```

Comment: Using `redirect` route property is correct